# Detect on macOS Cocoa if any network properties were changed

Tags: macos, cocoa, networking, reachability

How can I detect on macOS Cocoa if any network properties were changed? For example, detect if network interface were changed.

I want to get information about both type of changes: user triggering changes and changes triggered by any other causes. I need to implement bandwidth for user who can set limits for different networks.

Comment: Would check for interface configuration (SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll) help when you detect reachability change? Also add to question: Do you want to be notified about user triggering changes in settings or you care if your active connection changed it's properties.

Comment: I want to get information about both type of changes: user triggering changes and changes triggered by any other causes. I need to implement bandwidth for user who can set limits for different networks.

Comment: this might help https://superuser.com/questions/126642/throttle-network-bandwidth-per-application-in-mac-os-x First you need to find who does it and later you can look into their code using hopperapp

Comment: thank you for your advice, but  now my problem is detecting changes network properties. I told about bandwidth just to show context.